# Reading in a ASCII text file containing a matrix into a 2-D array (C language)

Tags: c, file-io

I have an ASCII file containing a matrix of real numbers. I want to read this matrix 
into a 2-D array in the C language. The ASCII file contains the 4x3 matrix looks like this:

```
2 3 4
4 5 6.7
3 4 8.9
3 4 5.9
```

Can anyone suggest  a quick way to do this? I have googled this but all solutions I see are pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double matrix[4][3];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read matrix[%d][%d]\n", i, j);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%6.2f", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

```
  2.00  3.00  4.00
  4.00  5.00  6.70
  3.00  4.00  8.90
  3.00  4.00  5.90
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!! But I had just one more question before pressing the accept button: Why did you write  if (scanf("%lf", &matrix[i][j]) != 1) what does the !=1 mean? Should I have used EOF instead?

Comment: The program expects to read a single long double. sscanf returns the number od fields it found, so if no double is found, an error must have happend. Cehcking for eof should work as well.

Comment: @Gaurish: as @sum1stolemyname said, in this context, checking for EOF would work as well as checking for `!= 1`.  However, if I'd optimized the calls by writing `if (scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &matrix[i][0], &matrix[i][1], &matrix[i][2]) != 3)`, foregoing the inner loop, then the `!= 3` would be crucial.  `scanf()` only returns EOF if it makes no conversions; if it converted 1 number and then found, say, a comma in the data, it would return 1, not EOF.  So, as a stylistic point, it is best to test that you got all the conversions you requested - there's a problem if you didn't get them.

Comment: Note that if there is a stray random letter in the data file; `scanf()` would not report EOF, but would report 0 items converted, repeatedly.  The test against the number of expected values is better than testing for EOF.  Also note that the code shown does not care if the numbers are laid out as 12 numbers on a single line, 1 number on every other line, in 6 lines with 2 numbers on each, in a ragged list, or any other variation you can think of.  It also does not check that there are exactly twelve numbers; there could be 21 million numbers in the file and the code reads the first dozen only.